# Unexpected Instant Transitions with @dnd-kit and react-hook-form's useFieldArray

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, dnd-kit

I'm currently facing an issue integrating @dnd-kit with react-hook-form's useFieldArray. I'm experiencing unexpected instant transitions whenever a dragged item is dropped.

To avoid immediate updates to the fields, I've created a separate copy for UI handling. However, the problem persists. Moreover, even when no updates are made to either the fields or react-hook-form's state, the transition is still instantaneous.

Code as can be found in the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rhf-dndkit-bs-kpyqrt?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A609-3638):

```js
type FormData = z.infer<typeof formDataSchema>

type UseSortableReturn = Omit<
  ReturnType<typeof useSortable>,
  'setNodeRef' | 'transform' | 'transition'
>

function SortableItem(props: {
  id: string
  children: (args: UseSortableReturn) => React.ReactNode
}) {
  const { setNodeRef, transform, transition, ...rest } = useSortable({
    id: props.id
  })

  const style = {
    transform: CSS.Transform.toString(transform),
    transition
  }

  return (
    <div ref={setNodeRef} style={style}>
      {props.children({ ...rest })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  const { control, setValue } = useForm<FormData>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formDataSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      people: new Array(6).fill(1).map((_, index) => ({
        fname: (index + 1).toString(),
        lname: (index + 1).toString()
      }))
    }
  })

  const modifiers = [restrictToVerticalAxis, restrictToParentElement]

  const { fields } = useFieldArray({ control, name: 'people' })

  const [items, setItems] = useState([...fields])

  useEffect(() => {
    fields.forEach((item, index) => {
      setValue(`people.${index}.fname`, items[index].fname)
      setValue(`people.${index}.lname`, items[index].lname)
    })
  }, [items, fields, setValue])

  return (
    <form className="w-full h-screen flex items-center justify-center px-8 max-w-screen-md mx-auto w-full">
      <div className="grid bg-green-400 p-2 gap-2 rounded">
        <DndContext
          modifiers={modifiers}
          onDragEnd={(event) => {
            const { active, over } = event
            if (over && active.id !== over?.id) {
              const oldIndex = items.findIndex((item) => item.id === active.id)
              const newIndex = items.findIndex((item) => item.id === over.id)
              const nextItems = arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex)
              setItems(nextItems)
              console.log(nextItems.map((i) => i.fname))
            }
          }}
        >
          <SortableContext items={items}>
            {items.map((field) => {
              return (
                <React.Fragment key={field.id}>
                  <SortableItem id={field.id}>
                    {({ attributes, listeners }) => (
                      <div className="bg-green-200 rounded py-2 px-4 flex items-center space-x-4 select-none">
                        <div
                          className="w-8 h-8 rounded bg-blue-300 -ml-2"
                          {...attributes}
                          {...listeners}
                        />
                        <div className="font-mono font-semibold text-green-950 flex space-x-4 py-5">
                          <span>{field.fname}</span>
                          <span>{field.id.toUpperCase()}</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </SortableItem>
                </React.Fragment>
              )
            })}
          </SortableContext>
        </DndContext>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: Could you write more details what is the problem and when it happens? I looked on sandbox and all looks fine.
Are you trying to slow down the transition?

Comment: The problem is that when releasing the item there is no transition. It instantly moves to where it should be. I've looked some more and it seems to be the norm if you are not using a drag overlay which seems kind of strange to me - why not allow for smooth transitions in this case??

Comment: You can make smooth the movement of elements which are moving under your dragging element [here](https://docs.dndkit.com/presets/sortable/usesortable#transition-1)